# Knockout render html string

Tags: knockout.js

Is there any way to render from a html string in knockout?

i.e

```
var html = ko.renderFromString('<p data-bind="text:name"></p>', {name:"Fred"});
```

It would be very convenient for what I'm doing.

```
$(".container").append(html);
$(".container").on("click", "p", function(e){
console.log(ko.dataFor(this));});
```

Comment: Have you seen this article? http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/10/ko-13-preview-part-3-template-sources.html It describes not exactly what you want but you could get some ideas from it.

Comment: Yes basically what you want is templating. You can also use the html binding, but in that case the viewmodel would already be bound.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're reluctant on messing with the Template Engines, try this:

```
ko.renderFromString = function (html, data)
    {
    var node = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    this.applyBindings(data, node.body);
    var res = node.body.innerHTML.toString();
    this.cleanNode(node);
    delete node;
    return res;
    };
```

It basically creates a temporary (in-memeory) DOM element from your Html string, binding your data, returning the `innerHTML` of the bound element then discarding it.

Comment: exactly what I wanted to accomplish.

Comment: Not bad 10000 in 7270ms I was getting 3869ms for a simple string.replace function I was using - but this opens up a lot more to me - thanks.

Comment: When are you calling `dataFor()`?

Comment: After I append the generated string to the dom and handle a delegated click event. I've added the code to the question

Comment: That's because i'm calling `this.cleanNode(node);` and `delete node;` in the `renderFromString` function (as i didn't know you're going to use that binding later, i thought it's only the render results you're interested in), try to remove this lines.